# Android BroadcastReceiver can't receive any broadcast events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created a BroadcastReceiver to detect SDCard mount and unmount
event, however, I am not able to receive any events at all:
here's the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="SDCardMountReceiver" android:exported="true" android:name="xxx.broadcasts.SDCardBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED"></action>
        <!-- or <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED" />--></intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the SDCardMountReceiver class:

```
public class SDCardBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SDCardBroadcastReceiver() {
        super();
        System.err.println("constructor");
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SDCardBroadCastReceiver", "receive " + intent.getAction());
        System.err.println("jonathan receive " + intent.getAction());

    }
}
```

Comment: anything suspicious in the logfile?

Comment: I suppose you need to give Uses Permission in Manifest file
try this
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" / hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED) javadoc specifies a different action:name value.
Use "android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" instead of "android.content.Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED"

Comment: I have tried the actualy string constant,android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED, but still not able to receive the broadcast. other thoughts?

Comment: I have tried creating the receiver dynamically in oncreate() on my Activity class, yet still nothing is received in onReceive of my SDCardBroadcastReceiver.
<pre>
SDCardBroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new SDCardBroadcastReceiver();
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
     registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
</pre>

Comment: I'm confused, if this didn't work then why did you mark it as the correct answer? Is the answer by chiuki correct, or this one?

Comment: I was having the same problem and his answer didn't solve the problem. Rather the answer by @chiuki, solved it. I had to add `<data android:scheme="file" />` to make the receiver work as required! Hope this helps to others!

Answer (score 45):

You also need to set the data scheme to "file".

```
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
     <data android:scheme="file" /> 
   </intent-filter>
```

Reference: [android-developers thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7aecbdc264f94081)

Comment: I never managed to make it work with defining in manifest, I needed to register it with code. Is ti possible to make this work with defining in manifest ?

Comment: Start a new question and post your `AndroidManifest.xml`. I'll take a look.

Comment: I cannot find the cause myself if didn't see your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you register a broadcast receiver programmatically, you must also set the scheme to "file".

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
filter.addDataScheme("file");
mContext.registerReceiver(mExternalStorageReceiver, filter);
```